# Prevent bruteforce attacks with recaptcha in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, recaptcha, brute-force, denial-of-service

I want to know how can I prevent my forms of brute force attacks.

I'll use recaptcha but I would not always show it in my forms.
I want to display it only when a bruteforce is detected.

For example if my login form recieves more than X requests in a period of time then bot is detected and display the recaptcha to block these spam bots.

Finally my question is:

There any example of this in .NET?

I googled it and I couldn't find anything similar, I also accept suggestions on how to do it if you know.

Thanks in advance :)

edit: Post corrected

Comment: You mentioned a register page and brute force... what would be brute forced on a register page?  For handling brute force attacks on your login page, the easy thing to do is just keep a "maxLoginAttempts" and "numberOfLoginAttempts" on your user store that gets updated whenever an attempt is made.  Once num has reached max, allow no more logins from the account until unlocked via admin.  As far as DDoS attacks, a captcha is only going to potentially protect your database, not your webserver.

Comment: CAPTCHAs do not prevent DoS attacks. The purpose is to prevent bots from *successfully* posting the form. However, the bot can very much still *unsuccessfully* post your form as much as it likes.

Comment: For both brute-force and DoS, the best method is to handle it at your firewall, denying requests from the same IP after a certain threshold. Anything you do at the application level is little more than a band-aid.

Comment: Also, the only thing CAPTCHAs are good for is pissing off *users*. Virtually every type of CAPTCHA can pretty easily be defeated by a bot. Google even accidentally broke ReCAPTCHA by releasing their Street View street number recognition algorithm, which works *really* well at identifying the characters in an image-based CAPTCHA.

Comment: Okay, I mean protect my database of being flooded with mass register, but I corrected the post anyway

Comment: personally I really dislike recaptcha from google, it pisses people off. Choose something different first like this [Post](http://www.stefanprodan.com/2012/01/user-friendly-captcha-for-asp-net-mvc/) or this [Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-of-a-simple-Captcha-f8c75c43) they are way more comforting to the eye...